# How to properly implement/inherit a ComboBox.ObjectCollection class for design-time usage?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

### SCENARIO

---

I subclassed the `ComboBox` class to design a kind of ComboBox control on which I can supply a custom type (`MyItem`) to its **ComboBox.Items** collection...

This is the subclassed ComboBox class:

```
<DesignerCategory("UserControl")>
Public Class MyComboBox : Inherits ComboBox

    <Editor(GetType(CollectionEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Items As MyItemCollection

    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me.Items = New MyItemCollection(owner:=Me)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)

        e.DrawBackground()
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()

        ' Check if it is an item from the Items collection.
        If (e.Index < 0) Then
            ' not an item, draw the text.
            Using brush As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top)
            End Using

        Else
            ' Get the item to draw.
            Dim item As MyItem = Me.Items(e.Index)
            Using brush As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top)
            End Using

        End If

        MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the subclassed `ComboBox.ObjectCollection` class:

```
<ListBindable(False)>
<DefaultMember("Item")>
Public Class MyItemCollection : Inherits ObjectCollection

    Sub New(ByVal owner As MyComboBox)
        MyBase.New(owner)
    End Sub

    <Browsable(False)>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
    Default Public Overloads Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As MyItem
        Get
            Return DirectCast(MyBase.Item(index), MyItem)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As MyItem)
            MyBase.Item(index) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' Original property:
    '
    '<Browsable(False)> 
    '<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
    'Default Public Overrides Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As Object
    '    Get
    '        Return MyBase.Item(index)
    '    End Get
    '    Set(value As Object)
    '        MyBase.Item(index) = value
    '    End Set
    'End Property

End Class
```

And finally this is the custom type `MyItem` that I will use for the Items collection of my control:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MyItem

    Public Property Text As String

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(String.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String)
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub

End Class
```

All this works fine at execution time, I can add items and it works as expected, the problem is that it won't work at design time...

### PROBLEM

---

When I try to add an item at design time like this:

[image]

...At first sight it seems it works, because I can add the item.

And the record seems properly auto-generated by Visual Studio in the Form's dsigner class (**Form1.Designer.vb**):

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.MyComboBox1 = New MyComboBox()
    Dim MyItem1 As MyItem = New MyItem()
    MyItem1.Text = "Test"
    Me.MyComboBox1.Items.AddRange(New Object() {MyItem1})

    ' ...
End Sub
```

Even more, If I try to determine at execution time the current amount of items that are inside the collection by calling the `Items.Count` property, it gives me the expected value:

```
Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form

    Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("There are '{0}' items in the collection.", 
                                      MyComboBox1.Items.Count))

    End Sub

End Class
```

...However, any of that matters, because when I launch the application I don't see the item(s) added at design time, I mean the items added at design time are not drawn in the control at execution time.

### QUESTION

---

What I'm missing to do?. How can I fix that?.

Please note that probably this IS NOT a drawing problem, because the items that I add through the `Items.Add()` and `Items.AddRange()` method at execution time are properly added and drawn.

I think maybe it could be some sort of issue about content synchronization...

I really don't know what is happening, because through the Object Inspector of Visual Studio I ensured to specify all the attribute classes to my classes, methods and properties, the same that are assigned by default for the `ComboBox.Items` property and the `ComboBox.ObjectCollection` class and the `ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Item` member.

Comment: You know you can add (almost) any type you'd like to the standard ListControls (CBO, ListBox), right?  If you override `ToString()` on `MyItem` the text will show up in the Collection Editor.  The problem with the items is (probably) that the base `ObjectCollection` class is not strongly typed. The collection editor wont know that instead of `Object` it really needs to create a MyItem type

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for comment. Yes, I know you can add any type to the default object collection, but doing that the VS designer will show you a default editor for an object collection (`<Editor(GetType(ObjectSelectorEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))>`) on which you only can add "raw" objects, no property of the object can be set, instead of using specific editor like I'm doing (`<Editor(GetType(CollectionEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))>`) on which you can set the properties of the object at design time.

Comment: The Collection Editor is already creating a `MyItem` object, above i shown the auto-generated code that adds VS after adding an item through the collection editor. I did not understood what you will mean which difference is suposed to be overriding the ToString function to represent a `MyItem` object as text, anyways I did it but it didn't solved the problem, as expected.

Comment: Shadowing the `Items` property is not equivalent to Overriding a virtual property.  All the base `ComboBox` methods that use the `Items` property will use the one defined in the `ComboBox` class.  You could set the base class backing field using reflection, but you will also need to account for any method that nulls the backing field as the [Items Property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,2e70da35bd2b8e9a,references) will recreate the backing field if it is Nothing.  The RefreshItems method nulls the backing field,

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks for comment. Then as for what you've explained, maybe this means a possible solution would be to shadow (those members that are not overridable) and/or to override all the other base methods (those that will use the base **Items** property instead) to call those base methods passing to them my custom **Items** property?. That is kinda work, but I can do it. I will try, thanks.

Comment: The RefreshItems dont take any argument,and the RefreshItem just takes an Integer argument.But I really think those methods maybe are not the real problem,See,the weird thing is that AFTER I added items at design-time through the control's designer on visual studio, and then after I execute the application and I attempt to add a single new item at execution time using the **Items.Add / Items.AddRange** methods (and ONLY after I attempt to do it at execution time), then after doing that the first item that I added at design time is drawn! (the new item is not).This behavior is breaking my head.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.  You are misunderstanding what I proposed.  You can Shadow the `Items` property, but you would need to re-implement the function of the `RefreshItems` method; it is overridable.  You would use Reflection to set the Combox's `itemsCollection` field to be an instance of `MyItemCollection`.  You would do this in both the constructor and the re-implemented `RefreshItems` method.  If you need help with that, I can post a hack job that I think should work.

Comment: @TnTinMn don't worry. And I can override it however I'm not sure about how to reimplement its logic, Anyways I'm not even sure whether that kind of modification and effort will really solve the problem... since the **RefreshItems** member seems to be called only when datasource or sorting changes are made. I still think maybe the real problem is another different thing, since I can add items at runtime and those items added at runtime are added properly, and drawn.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the only way to end this conversation is to post a working example.  May be then you can set some break points on that and learn from example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the technique I mentioned in the comments.  It is highly reliant of using Reflection to set a field in the ComboBox class as well as executing some methods in that class.  As such, it is subject to breaking if MS ever modifies these items.

Edit 2: Corrected Code

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
Imports System.Drawing.Design
Imports System.Reflection

<DesignerCategory("UserControl")>
Public Class MyComboBox : Inherits ComboBox
    Private fiItemsCollection As FieldInfo
    Private piCMItem As PropertyInfo
    Private miNativeClear As MethodInfo
    Private miObjectCollectionAddRangeInternal As MethodInfo

    Private _Items As MyItemCollection

    <Editor(GetType(CollectionEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Items As MyItemCollection
        Get
        Return Me._Items
        End Get
    End Property

    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        MyBase.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me.fiItemsCollection = GetType(ComboBox).GetField("itemsCollection", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Me._Items = New MyItemCollection(Me)
        fiItemsCollection.SetValue(Me, Me._Items)
        Me.piCMItem = GetType(CurrencyManager).GetProperty("Item", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Me.miNativeClear = GetType(ComboBox).GetMethod("NativeClear", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Me.miObjectCollectionAddRangeInternal = GetType(ObjectCollection).GetMethod("AddRangeInternal", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RefreshItems()
        Dim selectedIndex As Integer = Me.SelectedIndex
        Dim itemsCollection As MyItemCollection = Me._Items
        Me._Items = Nothing

        Dim destination As Object() = Nothing
        If ((Not MyBase.DataManager Is Nothing) AndAlso (MyBase.DataManager.Count <> -1)) Then
            destination = New Object(MyBase.DataManager.Count - 1) {}
            Dim args(0 To 0) As Object
            For i As Int32 = 0 To destination.Length - 1
                args(0) = i
                destination(i) = piCMItem.GetValue(MyBase.DataManager, args)
            Next i
        ElseIf (Not itemsCollection Is Nothing) Then
            destination = New Object(itemsCollection.Count - 1) {}
            itemsCollection.CopyTo(destination, 0)
        End If

        Me.BeginUpdate()

        Try
            If MyBase.IsHandleCreated Then
                Me.miNativeClear.Invoke(Me, Nothing)
            End If
            If (Not destination Is Nothing) Then
                Me._Items = New MyItemCollection(Me)
                Me.miObjectCollectionAddRangeInternal.Invoke(Me._Items, New Object() {destination})
                Me.fiItemsCollection.SetValue(Me, Me._Items)
            End If
            If (Not MyBase.DataManager Is Nothing) Then
                Me.SelectedIndex = MyBase.DataManager.Position
            Else
                Me.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
            End If
        Finally
            Me.EndUpdate()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        e.DrawBackground()
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
        ' Check if it is an item from the Items collection.
        If (e.Index < 0) Then
            ' not an item, draw the text.
            Using brush As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top)
            End Using
        Else
            ' Get the item to draw.
            Dim item As MyItem = Me.Items(e.Index)
            Using brush As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top)
            End Using
        End If
        MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thankyou!. One simple question: I will have problems using a DataSource? (because of the internal OnDataSourceChanged Event invocator that calls RefreshItems) or I don't worry about?

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I forgot to test using a DataSource and found an error where I tried to avoid a reflection call and use a Public method --> mistake.  The error is corrected and binding to a List(Of MyItem) works now.  You will get errors if the items are not of the MyItem type though.  This control should not be used as a general purpose replacement for the ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks for all. I'm aware of what you said at the end of your comment, the purpose of this control would be to provide a combobox with a imagelist, so that the control only should accept a specific custom type of item to display images, its a Image-ComboBox thingy.